# Circular dependency in Cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I've been sitting on this issue for a few days. I'm getting errors for `Circular dependency between resources: [ApiEcsEventsRuleProduct]` I also have a circular dependency error in `ApiEcsTaskDefinition` if I remove `ApiEcsEventsRuleProduct` altogether. The error doesnt make debugging obvious. Any help would be appreciated.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: API Service ECS extensions
Parameters:
  CoreStackName:
    Description: The name of the API Service Core stack
    Type: String
  KmsKey:
    Description: The ARN of the KMS configuration key
    Type: String
Resources:
  ApiEcsCloudwatchLogsGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Sub "/aws/ecs/${AWS::StackName}"
      RetentionInDays: 30
  ApiEcsCluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName: !Ref AWS::StackName
      ClusterSettings:
        - Name: containerInsights
          Value: enabled
  ApiEcsRepository:
    Type: AWS::ECR::Repository
    Properties:
      RepositoryName: !Ref AWS::StackName
  ApiEcsTaskExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      MaxSessionDuration: 43200
      RoleName: !Ref AWS::StackName
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonDynamoDBReadOnlyAccess
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: role-permissions
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - kms:Decrypt
                Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:kms:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:key/${KmsKey}"
  ApiEcsTaskInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Roles:
        - !Ref ApiEcsTaskExecutionRole
  ApiEcsTaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
      Family: !Ref AWS::StackName
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      Cpu: 2048
      Memory: 12288
      ExecutionRoleArn: !GetAtt ApiEcsTaskExecutionRole.Arn
      TaskRoleArn: !GetAtt ApiEcsTaskExecutionRole.Arn
      Volumes:
        - Name: temp_file
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: !Ref AWS::StackName
          Cpu: 2048
          Essential: true
          Memory: 12288
          Image: !Sub "${AWS::AccountId}.dkr.ecr.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${AWS::StackName}:latest"
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-group: !Ref ApiEcsCloudwatchLogsGroup
              awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
              awslogs-stream-prefix: ecs
          MountPoints:
            - SourceVolume: temp_file
              ContainerPath: /var/log/exported
  ApiEcsEventsRuleProduct:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Name: ExportProduct
      ScheduleExpression: "cron(10 3 * * ? *)"
      State: DISABLED
      Targets:
        - Id: Canada
          Arn: !Sub "arn:aws:ecs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:cluster/${AWS::StackName}"
          RoleArn: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole"
          Input: !Sub '{
            "containerOverrides": [{
              "name": "${AWS::StackName}",
              "command": ["Some command"],
              "environment": [{ "name": "ConfigTableName", "value": "${CoreStackName}-config" }, { "name": "JobHandlerTableName", "value": "${CoreStackName}-jobs" }, { "name": "AWS_REGION", "value": "${AWS::Region}" }]
            }]
          }'
          EcsParameters:
            LaunchType: FARGATE
            TaskDefinitionArn: !Ref ApiEcsTaskDefinition
            NetworkConfiguration:
              AwsVpcConfiguration:
                AssignPublicIp: DISABLED
                SecurityGroups:
                  - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${CoreStackName}-VpcSecurityGroup"
                Subnets:
                  - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${CoreStackName}-PrivateSubnet"
    DependsOn:
      - ApiEcsCluster
      - ApiEcsRepository
      - ApiEcsTaskDefinition
      - ApiEcsEventsRuleProduct
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
DependsOn:
  - ApiEcsEventsRuleProduct
```

The `ApiEcsEventsRuleProduct` resource cannot have a reference to itself.